# SQL how to select with the given condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

say we have a schedule table like this

```
course    day

  A       MONDAY

  A       WEDNESDAY

  B       MONDAY

  C       WEDNESDAY
```

my question is , how do i select the course whose day is on both Monday and Wednesday?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fiddle link for sample query execution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/19681/4/0)

```
create table schedule (course varchar2(10),day varchar2(20));
insert into schedule values('A','MONDAY');
insert into schedule values('A','WEDNESDAY');
insert into schedule values('B','MONDAY');
insert into schedule values('C','WEDNESDAY');

select s1.course
 from 
  schedule s1,schedule s2 
 where 
  s1.course=s2.course 
 AND
  s1.day='MONDAY'
 AND
  s2.day='WEDNESDAY';
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| COURSE |
----------
|      A |
```

Answer (score 2):

This type of problem is called Relational Division.

```
SELECT  course
FROM    tableName
WHERE   day IN ('Monday', 'Wednesday')
GROUP   BY course
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d956/1)

The solution is much more flexible than using join because the structure of the query will not change even you have another condition. *What if you want to search for three values? Will you provide another join?* Well on this query, only the values will change,

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*searching for three values*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f054/1)

Other Source(s):

- [SQL of Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)